# How do I adjust brightness only for one area of ​the monitor?

Tags: display, imac, hardware, screen

I've got an old iMac (2011) which I use as an external monitor from my MacBook Pro.
Half of the screen is dimmed because of a [known hardware problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=iumac%20half%20screen%20dimmed&sxsrf=APq-WBt5uxu0dUmW31bhmYXm-zeKIYTm1Q:1643891432897&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0mqDnxOP1AhVORfEDHcR1C9wQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1440&bih=764&dpr=2#imgrc=kb-WLxI-eGNszM)

Is there a way to calibrate only one area of the monitor, to adjust brightness and match the two areas?

[image: not my screen, but similar]
(not my screen, but similar)

Answer (score 1):

No - macOS applies calibration to the entire screen equally. Your best bet is to turn the Mac around and/or place an external display or remote in to that machine if you want to use the iMac as a proper computer.

In your case, this sadly is no longer fit for being an external display for your MacBook Pro.